# Pegando último valor de cada ID de acordo com maior ano final

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query

Tenho a seguinte *query*:

```
select f.id_user as user, f.id_tempo, t.ano_inicial, t.ano_final 
from fato as f inner join tempo as t 
where f.id_tempo = t.id_tempo;
```

Que me retorna a seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que devo utilizar na *query* para retorna apenas um registro de cada user levando em consideração o maior `ano_final` e, caso ano final seja igual a `0`, leve em consideração o maior `ano_inicial`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que o `ano_inicial` é armazenado como inteiro:

```
select f.id_user as user, f.id_tempo, t.ano_inicial, t.ano_final 
from fato as f inner join tempo as t
where f.id_tempo = t.id_tempo 
  and t.ano_inicial = (select MAX(t1.ano_inicial) 
                       fato as f1 inner join tempo as t1
                       where f1.id_tempo = t1.id_tempo and f.id_user = f1.id_user);
```

**editado**

considerando que possa haver mais de uma ocorrência de `ano_inicial` (retornando mais de um registro, como comentado), você limita o retorno:

```
select temp_table.id_user as user, temp_table.id_tempo, temp_table.ano_inicial, temp_table.ano_final 
from(
    select f.id_user as user, f.id_tempo, t.ano_inicial, t.ano_final 
    from fato as f inner join tempo as t
    where f.id_tempo = t.id_tempo 
      and t.ano_inicial = (select MAX(t1.ano_inicial) 
                           fato as f1 inner join tempo as t1
                           where f1.id_tempo = t1.id_tempo and f.id_user = f1.id_user);
) as temp_table
ORDER BY temp_table.id_tempo DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Quando o `id_user` possui no caso dois registros com o mesmo valor de `ano_inicial` ele mostra duas vezes. para no caso eu ter 1 registro apenas de cada `id_user` eu precisarei no caso ter um segundo verificador ou consigo dar um `distinct?`

Comment: @Doug, editei a resposta; espero que resolva ;)

Comment: Deu erro aqui mas to tentando corrigir...
Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: ops.. faltou isso, foi mal. Vou alterar novamente, mas é besteira

Comment: Se eu deixar com o `limit 1` ele só retorna 1 resultado

Comment: não testei, mas se você colocar o `distinct`, resolve? se não, a gente pensa num `where`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66592/discussion-between-doug-and-rlinhares).